# How to invoke Xtend code from Java?

Tags: java, code-generation, xtend

I have a code generator, which takes a syntax tree and converts it into a source file (text).

Basically, it traverses through all nodes of the tree, maps the node to text and appends the resulting texts to a `StringBuilder`.

Now I want the node to text mappers to be implemented using [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) like this:

```
public class NodeXMapper
{
    private XtendRunner xtendRunner = ...;

    public String map(final NodeX aNode)
    {
        return xtendRunner.runScript("def String map(NodeX aNode) {
            ''' «aNode.fieldX» - «aNode.fieldY» '''
        }", aNode);
    }
}
```

`xtendRunner.runScript(String aScript, final Object... aParams)` is a method, which passes the parameters `aParams` to Xtend script `aScript` and returns the result.

How can I implement that method?

**Update 1:** [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.xpand.doc%2Fhelp%2FXtend_language.html) I found this piece of code, which seems to run Xtend code in Java:

```
// setup
XtendFacade f = XtendFacade.create("my::path::MyExtensionFile");

// use
f.call("sayHello",new Object[]{"World"});
```

But I can't find `XtendFacade` class in the *Type hiearchy* view of Eclipse.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/648897/

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Thanks. The answer on that link says "A simple exmaple for an interpreter is included within the simple
arithmetics example". I can't find the simple arithmetics example in the sample projects in Eclipse. Where is it?

Comment: I think it is here: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/tree/master/examples/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.examples/contents/org.eclipse.xtext.example.arithmetics.ui

Comment: Here is a test base class that also uses XTendFacade: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/tree/master/examples/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.examples/contents/org.eclipse.xtext.example.arithmetics.ui, although it seems it it no longer in the repository elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The interpreter you found was for the old Xtend1 language, which is not what you are looking for.

The new [Xtend](http://xtend-lang.org) you are referring to is compiled, so there is no interpreter.

However, you could build an interpreted expression language using Xbase.  [See the documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/7languagesDoc.html#scripting) [and Github](https://github.com/xtext-dev/seven-languages-xtext/tree/master/languages/org.xtext.scripting) for an example on how to do that. Then you could run the interpreter of your expression language from Java.